# Power Bi / Filter Data from table by #Tags from a text field

Tags: powerbi, tags, dax, powerquery

Following Problem:

I have imported a table with n rows for n projects IDs and multiple columns. One column is a text field containing remarks. This text field may contain tags such as '#AB', '#CD', ... , which are nested in a string.

Example string: "Bla bla bla is related to #AB and #EF. bla bla"

A table of used #tags exists.

What I would like to do is filter my data by those tags. each project can contain no tags, one tag or multiple tags.

Addition: These filtering options should work:

- find projects with no #tag
- find projects with a specific #tag. Example only #AB
- find projects by multiple #tags. Example #AB or #CD or both

Suggestions? Thanks!

Cheers, Lorenzo

I actually have no idea where to start.

Comment: Seems like it might be easier to use PowerQuery to split the string into chunks and then keep just the "words" that start with a #.

Comment: Seems like it might be easier to use PowerQuery to split the string into chunks and then keep just the text strings that start with a #.
If you index your initial table, then split the column on [space], you'll end up with a column of "words" and the index. Then remove everything that doesn't start with #. Then you're sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure as below-

```
check_value_in_string = 

VAR _selected = SELECTEDVALUE (your_tag_table_name[tag_column_name])

RETURN
IF (
    CONTAINSSTRING ( SELECTEDVALUE (your_imported_table_name[remarks_column_name] ), _selected )
        || ISBLANK(_selected),
    1,
    0
)
```

Now add your filter and table with remarks. to the "filter on this visual" property of your table visual, add the new measure and select condition show value when = 1 and apply. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @mkRabbani! What works: filter by one specific #tag What does not work: *filter by 'no #tag' *filter by more than one #tag. Example: #AB or #EF or both. Any Ideas? For clarification I updated the description

Answer (score 0):

First write a Custom column

```
Custom = List.Count(List.Select(Text.Split([Remarks], " "), each Text.Contains(_,  "#")))
```

Write another Custom column

```
Custom.1 = if[Custom] = 0 then "No Tag" else if [Custom] = 1 then "One Tag"
else "More than one Tag")
```

Filter the Tags using Custom.1 slicer

[image]